# RISC-V: operation with a0 changes other register values

Tags: assembly, riscv, riscv32

I'm currently doing a small project on risc-v.
The problem is that, in a function, when I do something like this,

```
foo:
    ... 
    lw a3, 4(sp) 
    srli a2, a2, 16 
    srli a4, a4, 16
    add a0, a2, a4 
    ret
```

after executing add a0, a2, a4 the value of a2 and a4 also change. 
for e.g. 
if I comment out the add a0, a2, a4 and execute it, the result: a0 = 0x33333333, a2 = a4 = 0x00000000.
If I add the "add" line, the result becomes : 
a0 = ax000063e3, a3=0x123392c8, a4=0x00000d6e, a2 = 0x00005675.

Even it is the last statement of the function, it also changes the value of the registers that are above it. (like a3)

Am I missing something about risc-v? is it not sequentially executed?

Also in the function to make the result become 0,

```
...
beq a1, zero, exit_loop
...

exit_loop:
add a0, zero, zero
j finish

...
finish:
addi sp, sp, 28
ret
```

But this returns 0x00000001.If I'm understanding the fundamental parts of risc-v, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds unlikely.  Are you sure the registers had the same *initial* value before reaching the `add` (or the place where it was)?  Use a debugger to single-step the `add`.  Your first code block isn't a [mcve] because it depends on the initial values of `a2` and `a4`.  (But not the memory at `4(sp)` so IDK why you left that instruction in)

Comment: How are you testing these snippets of asm?  I'd guess that something is destroying register values before you look at them.  `add a0, zero, zero` should produce a `a0 = 0`.  Are you sure the "return value" you're looking at is actually `a0`?

Comment: sounds like a bug in your core.  what core are you using?

Comment: Try your code on a simulator, say, RARS.

Comment: In what environment are you seeing this behavior? Simulator? Hardware, and if so, which hardware? How are you observing it? It seems like something is awry in your setup or configuration.